# Shell Script to convert CSV file to XLSX

Tags: excel, shell, csv, unix, xlsx

How to convert CSV file to XLSX using shell script.

CSV Data-

column1;column2;column3;column4;column5

data1;data2;data3;data4;data5

data21;data22;data23;data24;data25

..

I want the above data properly aligned in fields/cells in excel format(XLS,XLSX).

Can we do it using awk, sed?

I have tried below method. It is generating excel file but even for less no. Of records, file size is in several MBs. Also while opening file it is throwing error - file format is not correct or data corrputed.

```js
echo "<table>"
tail -n +2 $CSV_FN | \
       sed -e 's/^/<tr><td>/' -e 's/;/<\/td><td>/g' -e 's/$/<\/td><\/tr>/'
echo "</table>"
```

*Note : ssconvert, Unoconv, xls2csv etc is Not allowed.*

Comment: Here is the [300 page standard describing XLSX](http://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-XLSX/[MS-XLSX].pdf).

Comment: And [the one for XLS](http://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-XLS/[MS-XLS].pdf) weighing in at 1100+ pages.

Comment: My point is: unless you have some massively reduced subset of XLS/XLSX you're targeting, saying "I have to do it manually without using any standard, established tools" seems unreasonable, and very broad.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yeah! true.. Thanks for your input.

Comment: what do you mean "but it is making file too heavy"? While a thankless task, I can't see any way of making the file smaller OR having it run faster, except with your own custom C-lang program, but given modern processors, `sed` or any other utility that can do text substitutions shouldn't be the road block to your problem. Good luck!

Comment: @shelter my shell script is generating a excel file which is too big in size. For some 10k records it is 40MB. Also while opening excel file it throws an error - file format not correct.

Comment: Did you make a 2 record .XLSX file, save it and then open it in a text editor? You'll need to do that, so you can see how what "preamble" data is needed. AND as I recall, XLSX files use a very proprietary MS version of XML filled with namespaces etc. Do you really want to become an expert in this? (You'll need to). ....

Comment: Regular tab-delimited (or CSV) files will accept small amounts of markup to force simple formatting (I'm almost sure I did that 10 years ago), so if your employer can accept less than 100% fidelity to XLSX, do some research on loading plain CSV files (with formatting), then post a new Q focusing on just that topic. Good luck. (P.S., note that my name has 2 L s in it ; -) )

Comment: See also SYLK format...